# How do I vary the Dojo TabContainer tabs based on my fields in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, dojo

I have a form in Django. I want each field in the form to be a tab in a Dojo TabContainer. This is what I'm doing:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="parameters_form" data-dojo-id="parameters_form" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div style="width: 350px; height: 290px">
        <div id="tc1-prog"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TabContainer, ContentPane){
            var tc = new TabContainer({
                style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"
            }, "tc1-prog");
            {% for field in form %}
                var cp = new ContentPane({
                     title: "{{ field.label_tag }}",
                     content: "{{ field.label_tag }}"
                });
                tc.addChild(cp);
            {% endfor %}
            tc.startup();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

However, when I load the page, nothing shows up and I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The issue was that `{{ field.label_tag }}` was inserting html into the javascript and causing errors. I changed it to `{{ field.label }}` and everything works.